# Does using "tío" imply a negative opinion?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I've seen the word *tío* used to mean "guy" or "bloke", but can't recall (in my admittedly limited experience) having seen it used to imply a positive opinion of someone.

If I refer to someone as "Ese tío" do I imply that I don't have a high opinion of them?

---

He visto la palabra *tío* usada para significar "guy" o "bloke", pero no puedo recordar (en mi limitada experiencia) haberla visto usada para implicar una opinión positiva de alguien.

¿Si me refiero a alguien como "Ese tío", estoy implicando que no tengo una alta opinión de el?

Comment: I'm not an expert because in Mexico we mostly use other slang words, but I've always interpreted *tío* as a [term of address](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/term_of_address) like *man* or *dude* in *Hey man!* but *tipo* is a noun that has the sense *guy* as in *Who is that guy over there?* As such the two are not interchangeable to me but I'd like to hear the real answers from the people that really know (-:

Comment: Thanks - all context is very welcome. Alas, where I live there are so few Spanish speakers that using slang is (for me) a very rare occurrence indeed.

Comment: Be aware, as other answers imply, that 'tío' is mostly used in Spain, not so much in Latin America.

Comment: In Perú is very common to use "tío" in the same meaning. Actually, I can't think in another word to translate "dude" or "man".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it has no negative connotation. It can mean *guy*, *bloke* or *dude*. It's rather informal slang used in Spain. In the second person it's often used as exclamatory.

> ¡Tío! ¿Pero qué (c...) es esto?"* - *Dude! What (the f...) is that?

Answer (score 6):

Su significado real es "uncle":

> El hermano de mi padre es mi tío.

En España, la palabra "tío" ha sufrido en las últimas décadas un cambio considerable en su significado. Tradicionalmente era un sinónimo de "señor" y se usaba (y se sigue usando en los pueblos pequeños) como señal de respeto y cariño y su traducción sería "mister" pues la palabra "señor" se reservaba exclusivamente para las personas ricas del pueblo o para las personas VIP

> He visto al tío Enrique = I have seen Mr. Enrique [ahí, "tío
>   Enrique" es una persona a la que quieres y respetas]
>
> He visto al señor = I have seen the rich man
>
> He visto al señorito = I have seen the rich man's son

Pero a partir de los 70's y 80's (excepto en la España rural) la palabra "señorito" empieza a desaparecer, la palabra "señor" se usa cada vez más asiduamente como "mister", y la palabra "tío" adquiere rápidamente un sentido comodín que se pueden usar tanto de forma afectiva (sinónimo de "amigo" «eh, tío» = «eh, amigo») como de forma neutra (sinónimo de "individuo" «ese tío vino anoche y compró galletas») y para evitar usar palabras malsonantes («estoy harto del tío éste» = «estoy harto de este idiota / imbécil / estúpido»)

---

Hoy en día (al menos en España) la palabra "tío" NO es negativa, pero sí se usa para suavizar palabras que podrían ofender a alguien:

> María enseñó **las tetas** por la TV ⟶ María enseñó **los pechos**
>   por la TV
>
> Antonio se hirió en **el culo** ⟶ Antonio se hirió **donde la
>   espalda cambia de nombre**
>
> Ese **estúpido** ha dicho que ... ⟶ Ese **tío** ha dicho que ...
>
> Este **gilipolllas** provocó el accidente ⟶ este **tío** provocó el
>   accidente
>
> ¡POLICÍA, este **ladrón**/ **joputa** /**desgraciado** me robó la
>   cartera! ⟶ ¡POLICÍA, este **tío** me robó la cartera

Comment: Thanks - that's very helpful. And you've [taught me a few choice phrases](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/611/130) there too.

Comment: "Tío" para decir "hombre" se usa desde el siglo XVI, no desde los 70 u 80 del siglo XX. Aquí una [referencia](http://curistoria.blogspot.com/2011/04/que-pasa-tio-ya-se-decia-en-el-siglo.html).

Answer (score 4):

El uso de la palabra tío no tiene ninguna connotación negativa (ni positiva) y es muy común en el lenguaje coloquial y vulgar en España. El uso es similar al uso que se aplica en inglés a dude, brother ...

> ¡Qué pasa tío!
>   Whats up, dude!
>
> No sabes de lo que me he enterado tío, ¡Pilar tiene novio!

En México y parte de sudamérica es común el uso de wey en lugar de tío.

Comment: no creo que "wey" sea lo suficientemente popular en sud américa (salvo en Chile) como para ponerlo como ejemplo. En Paraguay, Argentina, Uruguay y Bolivia nunca he escuchado un "wey"

Answer (score 2):

You could use it implying a positive opinion:

> ¡Qué gran tío!

or even

> ¡Pero qué gran tío!

Although it is true that it is commonly used to express neutrality, and in many cases it reflects a negative opinion, being a bit derogatory. Obviously, using `tío` with the meaning of `dude` or `guy` is only possible in very informal contexts, and generally, it is not acceptable in conversations in highly educated circles.

Comment: I suppose we don't use *guy* in formal or highly educated style either though I hesitate to call it slang. In those styles we'd just go with *person* or *man* as I suppose Spanish would prefer *persona* or *hombre*...

Comment: @hippietrail Or also *señor* in some cases, typically used to refer people who are much older than you :)

Comment: I would use *señor* as a term of address as in *desculpe señor* but not as a noun as in *el señor por allá* - but maybe that's because my Spanish isn't very good?

Comment: @hippietrail Not necessarily. Well, I don't understand what do you mean by *el señor por allá*, that doesn't make much sense to me. An example of using *señor* could be *Estaba paseando por el parque, y un señor me preguntó la hora*. If you say, *un tío me preguntó la hora*, it sounds more disrespectful. Alternatively, you could say instead *una persona me preguntó la hora*, omitting the fact that the person was probably older than you, and that he was a man. By the way, it is *DISculpe*.

Comment: Now you can see how bad my Spanish actually is (-: