# Ways used to refer to another person?

Tags: coloquialismos, vocabulario

## English

Ways used to refer to another person besides the following:

> - Huevon
> - Chavon
> - Chavo
> - Loco
> - Tio
> - Chico
> - Compadre

Could somebody point where and how each word could be used (e.g. place and context) and other possible variations.

---

## Español

Maneras de referirse a otra persona aparte de las siguientes:

> - Huevon
> - Chavon
> - Chavo
> - Loco
> - Tio
> - Chico
> - Compadre

Podría alguien apuntar donde y como pueden ser usadas (lugar y contexto) y otras posibles variaciones

Comment: In Mexico do not use Huevon to call your friends since it is a very rude way of saying the person is really lazy.

Comment: @SergioRomero I think Huevon is from Chile but not sure

Comment: Yes, huevón is used a lot in Chile.

Comment: This question is asking for a list of answers, which is not a good fit for a Q&A site.  Is there a more specific question we can answer for you?  Maybe you're looking for such a word that fits a specific context?

Comment: *<removed obsolete comments after conversation with OP via chat>*

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/468/12

Answer (score 2):

**English**

All over Mexico you can say:

> Güey

which is a deformation of the word "Buey" which means "Ox". This word can be used in a multitude of ways and contexts as it can mean at the same time: dumb/stupid, friend, enemy, guy, among others depending on the way you use it.

If you say something like:

> Que onda güey?

You are greeting your friend.

Another way is

> Cabrón

Which is a more rude way of calling a person. He would have to be a really good friend of yours since this word can also be used to insult someone.

**Español**

En todo México puedes usar:

> Güey

que es una deformación de la palabra "Buey". Esta palabra puede ser usada de múltiples formas y contextos y puede significar al mismo tiempo: tonto/estúpido, amigo, enemigo, tipo, sujeto, entre otros dependiendo de la forma como lo uses.

Si dices algo como:

> Qué onda güey?

Estas saludando a tu amigo.

Otra forma es decir:

> Cabrón

Esta es una forma muy grosera de llamar a una persona. La persona a quien llames así debe de ser muy amigo tuyo o le debes de tener mucha confianza ya que también puede ser utilizada para insultar a alguien.

Answer (score 2):

## English

In Mexico and Central America:

> - vato
> - [güey](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%BCey)
> - carnal
> - [paisano](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paisano#Spanish)

In Venezuela and some other Caribbean countries:

> pana

In Ecuador:

> ñaño

In Perú:

> - pata
> - causa

In Agentina:

> [tipo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tipo#Spanish) (*very informal*)

---

## Español

En Mexico y centroamérica:

> - vato
> - [güey](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%BCey#Espa.C3.B1ol)
> - carnal
> - [paisano](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/paisano)

En Venezuela y otros países del Caribe

> pana

En Ecuador:

> [ñaño](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%B1a%C3%B1o#Espa.C3.B1ol)

En Perú:

> - pata
> - causa

En Agentina:

> [tipo](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/tipo) (*muy informal*)

Answer (score 2):

En España, entre amigos, todo el mundo dice “tío” (*guy, dude*), desde el presidente del gobierno hasta la persona más humilde. La excepción podrían ser las personas mayores de las zonas rurales.

En la conversación normal, hablando coloquialmente, “tío” es universal en España. Llega a cansar, aunque en situaciones formales no se usa nunca.

Otras alternativas, menos frecuentes, se utilizan en contextos más reducidos:

-chaval (*lad*)

-macho (*man*)

-colega, socio (*buddy, mate*)

-chico (*boy*)

-tronco (*buddy, mate*)

-majo

Un extranjero que resida en España, sobre todo si es joven, acabará diciendo “tío” sin darse cuenta, y deberá llevar cuidado de no emplear la palabra en situaciones formales o semiformales, o con personas mayores. El resto de las palabras que menciono son de uso más difícil y solo son comunes en ciertas situaciones o regiones. No son realmente necesarias.

Las demás palabras que menciona el autor de la pregunta (huevón, chavón...) no se usan normalmente en España, aunque se entienden.